# Can i ping a list of sites in a certain order?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, console-application, ping

Afternoon All,

Im in the process of writing my first console app in VB.  The app i am developing that essentially pings a list of web sites and then writes the status out.

My question is the following...

Is there a way for me to order the websites that i wish to ping in my VB.  At the moment i just list this and it doesnt matter what order i write these sites in the ping command seems to pull back the write out the status of the quickest repsonce.  The trouble is i have a couple of sites  that are located on the same web box and the status message seems to mess up when writing out the status.  I think that this is due because they have the same response time.

Please find the code i have been using...

```
'Imports ping class
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Console.Title = ("Daily Checks PING to Check Current Status")
    Dim myPingList As New List(Of String) 'A LIST TO HOLD SOME STRINGS
    Dim myPing As Ping = Nothing          'PING CLASS 
    Dim timeout As Integer = 100000         'TIMEOUT FOR PING REQUESTS


    'ADD A BUNCH OF THINGS TO PING
    myPingList.Add("website1")
    myPingList.Add("website3")
    myPingList.Add("website2")


    'LOOP THE STRING LIST OF PLACES WE WANT TO PING
    For Each ItemToPing As String In myPingList

        'CREATE A NEW PING OBJECT
        myPing = New Ping

        'ADD EVENT HANDLER FOR THE PING COMPLETED EVENT
        'PingResult IS THE SUB ROUTINE BELOW
        AddHandler myPing.PingCompleted, _
                   AddressOf PingResult

        'TELL USER WHAT IS BEING PINGED
        'Console.WriteLine("Sending PING Request To: " & ItemToPing)

        'SEND ASYNC PING REQUEST
        'myPing.SendAsync(ItemToPing, timeout, Buffer, ItemToPing)
        myPing.SendAsync(ItemToPing, timeout, ItemToPing)
    Next

    'WAIT FOR A KEYPRESS TO CLOSE CONSOLE WINDOW
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("Critical Systems Ping Results:")
    Console.ReadKey(True)

End Sub

'THE PING RESULT THAT WILL FIRE WHEN A PING COMPLETES
Private Sub PingResult(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingCompletedEventArgs)

    'OUTPUT TO USER, e.UserState IS WHAT WE PASSED IN AS THE UserToken (ItemToPing) IN THE ABOVE CODE
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("***********************************")
    Console.WriteLine("Application: " & e.UserState.ToString)

    ''IF THERE WAS AN ERROR THEN OUTPUT INFORMATION ABOUT THE ERROR
    ''OTHERWISE OUTPUT INFORMATION ABOUT THE RESULT OF THE PING REQUEST
    ''THE EVENTARGS e HAVE A LOT OF INFORMATION IN THE e.Reply VARIABLE
    If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & e.Error.Message)
        If e.Error.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine("More Info: " & e.Error.InnerException.Message)
        End If
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Status: " & e.Reply.Status.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("Round Trip Time: " & e.Reply.RoundtripTime.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("Response Buffer Length:" & e.Reply.Buffer.Length.ToString)
    End If
    Console.WriteLine("***********************************")


    'THE SENDER IN THE ARGUMENTS IS THE PING OBJECT THAT WE CREATED
    'SO NOW REMOVE THE EVENT HANDLER LISTENER AS IT IS NO LONGER NEEDED
    'AND CALL Dispose() ON THE PING CLASS TO CLEAN UP UNMANAGED RESOURCES
    With DirectCast(sender, Ping)
        RemoveHandler .PingCompleted, AddressOf PingResult
        .Dispose()
    End With

End Sub

End Module
```

There is probaby a better way to complete / write this task but the above is a start.
Any help is much appreciated.

Regards
Betty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see it, you have two options:

1. buffer the results.  Collect all the results, only display them after all complete.  This will likely be the fastest execution of the two options, but it could delay showing results.
2. queue the pings and wait for one to complete before starting the next.

You're using `SendAsync` which means, well, it is *asynchronous* by design.  That's a choice you made in code.  You can use a *synchronous* command if you'd prefer to keep them in order (i.e. `Send`).  Or if you still want them to be Asynchronous for some reason, you also have things like semaphores and mutexes to halt execution on the next iteration... lots of options here, you just need to pick the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Ping.SendAsync(), which is an asynchronous method, for each IP address so the responses will not necessarily return in the same order that they were sent.

Can you use the Ping.Send() method instead?